# Nginx redirect to html file

Tags: nginx

How to return a simple html file in the processing of older browsers. This is a file in the system. Example [nginx.conf](https://gist.github.com/joelmoss/233840)

```
if ($ancient_browser) {
   return /fuul/path/to/file/browser.html; #- how?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an if statement to do a conditional rewrite. (see http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) Replace the words between bars like "foo" with the user agent strings you want to match against. You may want a location that has a different document root from your default location. Using `last` is transparent to the user. `redirect` results in a 302.

```
### case sensitive http user agent blocking  ###
if ($http_user_agent ~ (FooSomething|BarElse) ) {
  rewrite ^ /static-html/your-browser-too-old.html last;
}
### case insensitive http user agent blocking  ###
if ($http_user_agent ~* (foo|bar) ) {
  rewrite ^ /static-html/your-browser-too-old.html last;
}

location /static-html {
  root /var/www/static-html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [rewrite directive](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite) in the nginx docs.  I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Read, but I just have not found the "return file"

Comment: I don't think it'll be a `return`, it'll be a `redirect` to that file so that nginx will render it.  See http://www.faultserver.com/q/answers-configure-nginx-to-render-static-files-and-rewrite-file-extension-or-proxy-pass-438234.html